# exclude both 'provided' & 'test' dependencies with dependency-plugin

Tags: java, maven, maven-dependency-plugin

is there a way to exclude both 'provided' and 'test' dependencies using maven dependency plug-in:

1. with 'mvn dependency:tree | grep compiled' I'm getting one set of jars (which will be included into final war)
2. and with 'mvn dependecy:build-classpath -DexcludeScope=provided' I'm getting different set jars for both 'test' & 'compile'

so is there a way to get 1st set of jars using dependency plugin options?

Comment: may be more correct question would be how to get exactly the same dependencies as ones used by war plugin (i.e. which are being copied to WEB-INF/lib)

Answer (score 1):

'-Dscope=runtime' or '-DincludeScope=runtime' (depending on the [goal](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/usage.html) being used) will restrict the plugin to examining dependencies used in the runtime scope